# please how to creat tow listeview in one page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

please i need to creat tow listeview contains containers

I mean like those pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should share the code you've already tried. Please check the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You might want to learn how to use this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

I can only share a snippet of code since I've implemented it in a medium scale application, and cannot share the entirety of the code; but it should look something like this:

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
crossAxisCount: 1,
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
itemCount: pharmacyBranchSearchedProvider.pharmacyBranches.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    PharmacyBranch pharmacyBranch =
        pharmacyBranchSearchedProvider.pharmacyBranches[index];

    return PharmacyBranchCard(
    pharmacyBranch: pharmacyBranch,
    onPressed: () {
        Provider.of<ProductFilterProvider>(context)
            .resetProductTypesWithJsonMap(
                pharmacyBranch.productTypes);
        PageRouter.push(
            context,
            PharmacyBranchProductSearchPage(
            pharmacyBranch: pharmacyBranch,
            ));
    },
    );
},
staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
)
```

You can build something like the one you referenced, listing multiple products per row; which in the code above, is the `crossAxisCount` which defines how many widgets will be displayed per row.